# Boost regulator: Unexpected output voltage

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I just finished setting up an [LM2577](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1577.pdf) as a boost converter, and have run into some unexpected issues.

For starters, here is the recommended "typical application circuit":

[image: Application Circuit]

My application circuit is slightly different. At the 5V input, I can actually have anything between a 8V to 14V input as part of a PMOS common source setup so I can turn off the current coming in to the circuit, like so:

[image: Modified Circuit]

However, the output voltage is nothing like what I expected. I had assumed that if I'm drawing at least a few dozen milli-amps, and have a +9V DC rail at the source of the PMOS, I should expect just under 9V at the drain of the PMOS when it's turned on, and that the output voltage of the boost regulator, **Vcc**, would be approximately 12V. My assumption was also that the output voltage is just a function of the external discrete components connected to the regulator, and not the input voltage (ie: 9V DC) provided the input voltage to the regulator is less than the output voltage it generates. Is this assumption correct? I want the regulator to always output a fixed voltage (ie: 12V) for a wide range of input voltages (ie: 7.5V to 10.0V).

Also, the output voltage I initially measured was much greater than expected, a whopping 41V. When I removed the 0.1uF capacitor that connects the input to **GND**, it went back down to +15VDC. How can this be happening? Is it because the input to the regulator is from a PMOS drain and not a supply rail?

Comment: Try driving VIN directly from a supply rail (bench supply perhaps?) to verify the regulator is working. Measure the voltage across R11 (FBck), expect 1.23V if the feedback is working correctly. Confirm feedback network R10 and R11 are 1% tolerance. May need to add 220uF across C9 -- see data sheet figure 31.

Comment: did you actually build this? or is this all in simulation? Have you checked that it's not a hardware/soldering issue?

Comment: Most of the spec's for the LM2577 are for 100mA-800mA load currents. What happens to the output when you apply a more substantial output?

Comment: @KyranF I actually built the circuit. I don't see any misplaced contacts (solderless BB).

Comment: seems like a strange behaviour indeed, It "should just work" unless something went wrong. The IC itself might actually already be damaged/broken so any further testing may be useless. Have you tried putting in a brand new LM2577?

Comment: @KyranF I replaced the IC, but not joy.

Comment: @helloworld922 So, this won't act as a constant voltage source unless it's drawing a substantial load then?

Comment: @MarkU I still have the same issue when powering from the 9V battery rail. The voltage across R11 is correct, and the tolerances on R10 and R11 are also 1%. I tried putting C9 in parallel with a 220uF cap to ground, but no luck. Is this possibly because I'm drawing very little load at the moment? (10mA).

Comment: Does it makes sense that if **Vin** is coming from the drain of the PMOS, that the capacitor C9 builds up to a higher voltage than the 9V rail supplying the PMOS? This is causing **Vds** to become negative, and starts turning the PMOS into what I'm assuming is triode region.

Comment: After paying closer attention, it seems that the 680uF capacitor is searing hot to the touch.

Comment: @Dogbert it's possible the capacitor has failed, either due to polarity, ripple current ratings not good enough, solder issue, over voltage failure, or some other cause. Replace the cap if you can, and test again..

Comment: @KyranF I swapped out the cap, but no good. The circuit still ramps up to 40V. Is this because I'm not drawing much load? I thought the point of a switching regulator was to act as a constant voltage source for varying input voltages.

Comment: @Dogbert the only way I can see the output going to 40V is something is wrong with the inductor or the feedback resistor network.

Comment: @Dogbert also, it keeps mentioning 100mA load currents everywhere, try putting a load resistor to give 100mA load on the desired voltage if you can. Also, can you tell us exactly what capacitor you are using? As in, it's ratings, chemistry/material, size etc.

Comment: Have you looked at the input and output voltages on a scope?  You could have oscillations going on.  A switch mode converter has a negative incremental input impedance, meaning you have to feed it with a low impedance source (lower than Zin across the entire converter bandwidth) or you will get oscillation.  (Google the Middlebrook criterion.)  Does it work when powered from a bench supply?  You should add some bulk capacitance right at the input to the part if running from a higher impedance source. A few hundred uF should help.

Comment: @KyranF The output capacitor is a 680uF 25V electrolytic polarized aluminum capacitor. I don't draw more than 20mA at the moment. I wanted to get the circuit up and running prior to moving on to adding the full load.

Comment: @JohnD Unfortunatley, I don't have a bench power supply. I have a 6V wall wart, but it yields the same results.

Comment: @Dogbert And no scope to see if the output is oscillating?  It could be reading an average value on your DMM.  That could also explain why the output cap is getting so hot.  (Though the output caps on a boost have to handle significant ripple current.)

Comment: @JohnD I figured it out, and posted the answer below. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: @KyranF I figured it out, and posted the answer below. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: Just fty: Solderless breadboard is not a good technique for switch-mode power supplies in general. The inductance and contact resistance cause trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I was using a **partially** correct application circuit. According to [this link](http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/lm2577-switching-regulator.php), it turns out that when using the fixed output version of this chip, I need to short the feedback (pin 2) to the output of the Schottky diode, and I'm all set.

> The schematic is simple, easy to build and cost effective, producing
>   12V from a 5V unregulated supply with a maximum output current of
>   800mA. Pin numbers shown are for the TO-220 package (LM2577T-ADJ).
>
> The design uses the adjustable version of LM2577, but the 12V
>   fixed-voltage version (LM2577T-12) will also work if you remove R1 and
>   R2 and connect the feedback pin directly to the regulator's output.
>   The UC2577 - a pin to pin compatible replacement available from Texas
>   Instruments can also be used.